# Cleaner alternative to jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you guys know a better way to display this piece of code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "#f1f1f1" });
    });
    $("input[type='text']").focusout(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "white" });
    });
    $("input[type='email']").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "#f1f1f1" });
    });
    $("input[type='email']").focusout(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "white" });
    });
    $("input[type='password']").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "#f1f1f1" });
    });
    $("input[type='password']").focusout(function() {
        $(this).css({ "background-color" : "white" });
    });
});
```

Could I shorten the code above into a smaller function?

Comment: Why don't you use css? You dont need javascript for this.

Comment: I have added an answer to achieve this with CSS, might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no JavaScript required here as this can be achieved in CSS alone:

```css
input {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

input[type=password]:focus,
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wm6eh8vz/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password']").focus(function() {
        $(this).css({"background-color" : "#f1f1f1"});
    });
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password']").focusout(function() {
        $(this).css({"background-color" : "white"});
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, no idea why I didn't just try this myself. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**CSS**

```
.grey {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $inputs = $('input[type=email], input[type=text], input[type=password]');
    $inputs.on('focus', function() {
        $(this).addClass('grey');
    });
    $inputs.on('blur', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('grey');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(
```

shortcut is

```
$(function(
```

To reduce the number of times you need to specify the selector (and reduce risks of typos), you can pass the events as an array:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password']")
    .on({
       focus: function() { $(this).css({"background-color" : "#f1f1f1"},
       focusout: function() { $(this).css({"background-color" : "white"}
    );
});
```

Or you can chain the statements (my preference):

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],input[type='password']")
    .on("focus", function() { $(this).css({"background-color" : "#f1f1f1"})
    .on("focusout", function() { $(this).css({"background-color" : "white"});
});
```

Recommend you use `.addClass` / `.removeClass` with css classes as it will allow you to change the style more easily (eg if you want to add a glow-box around the input).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in CSS, you could possibly do this,

```
input[type='text'], input[type='email'], input[type='password'] {
    background-color : white;
}
input[type='text']:focus, input[type='email']:focus, input[type='password']:focus {
    background-color : #f1f1f1;
}
```

**Note:**
CSS does not consume process, but javascript does. It is always best to use CSS wherever possible.

Hope this helps.